# Retrofit response not being entirely parsed

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I have an Android application that uses a RestFUL web service as its backend. I already implemented Retrofit for sending registration data and it works. 
Now I need to get a big load of objects, but it's not working yet. I noticed Gson only parses a few attributes (name, type, location), but most of them were not (specially id).
How does Gson actually parse it? Do I actually have to implement it? From what I thought I just needed the name of the attributes to match and it would do all the work for me.

This is how I am building my Gson and RestAdapter:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
        .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTypeAdapter())
        .create();

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(PACURL.getHost())
//                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
        .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
        .build();
```

My request definition:

```
@POST("/pois/{category}")
    void getPois(@Path("category") String category,
                 @Query("lat") Double lat,
                 @Query("long") Double lon,
                 Callback<WrapperPois> callback);
```

And the actual call:

```
NetworkInterface nt = restAdapter.create(NetworkInterface.class);
nt.getPois(category,
        location.getLatitude(),
        location.getLongitude(), callback);
```

I used Retrofit expecting to ease my work, so please let me know if I have to actually write the deserialization myself. Any comments on how Gson default converter works is very appreciated.

Thanks!

- Edit:

My WrapperPois class:

```
public class WrapperPois {
    public ArrayList<Poi> results;

    static class MyResponse {
        public ArrayList<Poi> array;
    }
}
```

And the Poi contains:

```
protected String objectId;
protected String url;
protected String type;
```

...

Comment: can you post your WrapperPois class?

Comment: Added part of my code. Basically I created these classes to match my response.

Comment: the names of the fields in your classes are the same as the names in json?

Comment: Yes, it actually happens that my super class has the attribute "id", but as the json has "objectId" I created this specific attribute "objectId" just to get it from the json. But it's not working :(

Comment: can you add the json that your want to parse with this class?